# Bootstrap swap grid spans

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a Bootstrap template and while I'd like the large grid to remain in the correct order of span4 then span8... I'd like them to reverse to span8 then span4 when the screen size is under 768. I don't want to use js on this... so I'd wondering if there is a way, and how so, to float the spans left then under 768 right. Or maybe there is a better way.

**Diagram**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">Hello</div>
  <div class="span8">World</div>
</div

screen width greater than 768 displays Hello World
screen width less than or equal to 768 displays World Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class of 'right' to the span8, then set a media query to float: right when less than 768.

Comment: That doesn't work. I don't think you understand the question, I'll diagram it out.

Comment: Add class of 'right' to span4? By default, those are float: left. So, if you float the first one right (span4), it should be on the right side. Then it would say, World Hello. If this does not work, maybe do a jsFiddle.